# For all prime $p$ and $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, how to prove $p\mid a^p+(p-1)!a$ and $p\mid a+(p-1)!a^p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\forall p$ (prime) $\forall a\in \Bbb Z$, how to prove:

$$p\mid a^p+(p-1)!a$$

$$p\mid a+(p-1)!a^p$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Fermat's little theorem
- Wilson's theorem

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- Reexpress $ p | a^p + (p-1)! a $ as a modular arithmetic expression $ a^p \equiv - (p-1)! a \mod p $.
- Look up the theorems given by Zev Chonoles and try to move towards the modular arithmetic expression.
- $ a \equiv b \mod p $ and $ c \equiv d \mod p $ implies $ ac \equiv bd \mod p $.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Apply a little $\rm\color{#0A0}{Fermat}\ $ and $\ \rm\color{#C00}{Wilson}\ $ below

$\ \begin{eqnarray}\rm a^p\!\!&+&\rm \ a\  (p\!-\!1)! &=\,&\rm  \color{#0A0}{a^p\!-a}\: +\: a\ (\color{#C00}{1+(p\!-\!1)!})\\
\rm a\,&+&\rm a^p (p\!-\!1)! &\,=\, &\rm  \color{#0A0}{a-a^p} + a^p(\color{#C00}{1+(p\!-\!1)!})\end{eqnarray}$